# Made new pokemon go account using same google account accidentally and cant get back to old one

Tags: pokemon-go

I made a new Pokemon GO account but I used the same google account, so now every time I try to play it makes me use the new account instead of the lvl 17 one. I tried signing out and logging into the google account, but it makes me go into the new account instead of the old one. So now I have no way of accessing the old one. I tried submitting a request to Niantic to delete the new account so hopefully it would bring me to the old account when I sign in that google account, but they haven't answered yet and I don't know if that would work. Is there any other way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I know you don't want to hear this, but your old account is likely gone.

Occasionally, a bug will affect player accounts causing them to be reset back to zero or deleted altogether. From this point onwards, the only way to keep playing is to re-create the account.

As you're certain that you're using the same Google account, the only reasonable conclusion is that your data is gone into the digital ether.